# Warning in Source Settings in TFS 2010 build; This build wastes time and computer resources because your working folders

Tags: tfs

I get a warning when I save my build definition;

The build definition workspace mapping contains potential problems.

This build wastes time and computer resources because your working folders include the team projects (project), which includes a Drops folder. You should cloak the Drops folder.

I am not aware that I have the Drops folder anywhere in my solution so why am I getting this message and how do I fix it?

An image as requested;
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my TFS build waste time eventhough there is no Drops folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901044/why-does-my-tfs-build-waste-time-eventhough-there-is-no-drops-folder)

Comment: I looked at that, but the answer to that question does not help me.

Comment: You added a "Drops" folder and cloaked it in the workspace? That seems to be the workaround.

Comment: My drop folder is a on a network drive. It seems a crazy thing to add it to my solution and then cloak it. I am not sure I even know how to do that.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your Source Settings for the build definition?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?